# Relational calculus expression for projection (Database Management)

Tags: database-theory, relational-calculus, tuple-relational-calculus

### I recently came across this question:

Let the following relation schemas be given:

$R=(A,B,C)$

$S=(D,E,F)$

Let relations r(R) and s(S) be given. Give an expression in the tuple relational
calculus that is equivalent to the following:

### a. $\pi_A(r)$

The solution provided is:

### $\{t|\exists q \in r(q[A]=t[A])   \}$

But according to me, the solution should have been:

$\{t|\exists q \in r(t[A]=q[A])   \}$

---

Can anyone please help me in fiding out where my error is, or whether I am correct??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $x=y$ then $y=x$. The two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: Hey Derek, thanks for the comment. But I couldnt get your point. Can you please elaborate a bit? Thank you

Comment: Derek's pointing out that the only difference between the provided solution compared to your solution is the order of operands to `=`. If you think that order of operands in TRC is significant, please give a reference.